# Send Protobuf via Websocket in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

I'm trying to send an serialized protobuf-message via WebsocketApp to a Server.
When i serialize the protobuf-message (proto_message), i get the folowing binary value:

b'\x08\x8e\xd6\xad\xc9\xfa0\x10\x02"\x00'

I use the following code to send the message via Websocket-App:

```
ws.send(proto_message.SerializeToString(), opcode=2)
```

The message doesen't get accepted by the server. When i check the websocket-Trace, i see the following messages:

++Sent raw: b'\x82\x8b\x14\xd8\xe4A\x1cV2\xec\xdd"\xd4Q\x16\xfa\xe4'
++Sent decoded: fin=1 opcode=2 data=b'\x08\x8e\xd6\xad\xc9\xfa0\x10\x02"\x00'

It seems that the WebsocketApp doesnt send the binary data as expected. The raw data doesn't reflect the data from proto_message. Any idea why?

Receiving and parsing of incoming protobuf messages works without problems.

Thank you